# CircleCI "Some errors occurred while attempting to infer information about your code"

Tags: android, continuous-integration, circleci

I'm trying to build an Android project using CircleCI, but every time I run a build, the build completes in the Configure Build task and I get this message:

**Some errors occurred while attempting to infer information about your code.**

Also, when this occurs, CircleCI automatically tries to rebuild the branch, causing a loop, because every new build keeps failing.

Here's my circle.yml file

```
version: 1
machine:
  java:
    version: oraclejdk8
  environment:
    # Java options
    JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms512m -Xmx2048m"
    GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"

dependencies:
  pre:
    # Install the android packages
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-25.0.3"

test:
  pre:
    override:
    # Generate a debug-apk
    - ./gradlew assembleAppseeOffDebug -PdisablePreDex

    # Copy the generated apk files to Circle-CI Artifacts
    - cp -r app/build/outputs/apk/ $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS

    # Copy the test results to Circle-CI Artifacts
    - cp -r app/build/outputs/androidTest-results/* $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by following [this circle.yml example](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/android/#building-android-projects-manually)

In [1](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/android/#building-android-projects-manually), after the **test** tag there's an **override** tag, but in my circle.yml file there's a **pre** tag. Removing that **pre** tag solved the problem.

Final circle.yml file

```
version: 1
machine:
  java:
    version: oraclejdk8
  environment:
    # Java options
    JAVA_OPTS: "-Xms512m -Xmx2048m"
    GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"

dependencies:
  pre:
    # Install the android packages
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-25.0.3


test: 
  # REMOVED pre TAG
    override:    
    # Generate a debug-apk
    - ./gradlew assembleAppseeOffDebug -PdisablePreDex

    # Copy the generated apk files to Circle-CI Artifacts
    - cp -r app/build/outputs/apk/ $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS

    # Copy the test results to Circle-CI Artifacts
    - cp -r app/build/outputs/androidTest-results/* $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS
```

Comment: Also, `version: 1` isn't part of the CircleCI 1.0 design spec and shouldn't be there.

Comment: Most phases, let `test ` can have different steps. `pre` happens before CircleCI's inferred commands and `post` happens after. `override` tells CircleCi to not use inferred commands and instead, only the commands you specify.